# Comparing Time - Python

Tags: python, datetime, variables, math

I have a function where I read the time from a file. I put this into a variable. I then subtract this value from the current time which most of the time will give me a value around .

My problem is im not sure how to check if this value which I attach to a variable is greater than say 20 seconds.

```
def numberchecker():
    with open('timelog.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        data=myfile.read().replace('\n','')

    a = datetime.strptime(data,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
    b = datetime.now()
    c = b-a   (This outputs for example: 0:00:16.657538)

    d = (would like this to a number I set for example 25 seconds)


    if c > d:
        print ("blah blah")
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
if c.total_seconds() > datetime.timedelta(seconds=d):
    print ("blah blah")
```

Comment: when I assign an int to d (e.g.10), I then get the error 
TypeError: unorderable types: datetime.timedelta() > int()

Comment: convert d to a timedelta:
`datetime.timedelta(seconds=d)`

Answer (score 0):

The difference which you're getting is a `timedelta` object.

You can just use `c.seconds` to get the seconds.

Comment: Added comment to wrong answer. And I did that and still get error

Comment: Use `c.seconds > d` instead of just `c > d`